# Using the OutputStream of the Bluetooth connection in an other thread disturbs receiving of messages

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, outputstream

I followed the Android Guide to build a Bluetooth connection.

To separate things and make them independent, I decided to take the sending part of the BT to a separated thread. To achieve this, I pass the "OutStream" of the BT-Socket to a separated Thread class. My problem is, as soon as I start this thread, the incoming messages are not well red anymore.

But I don't know why, because I do not use this Thread at the moment. It is started but no messages are written in it.

This is part of the "ConnectedToDevice"-Class which receives the messages. I use a special way to detect that my Messages are received completely.

```java
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;

    sendPW();
    int len = 0;

    Communication.getInstance().setFrequentSending(OVS_CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS);
    Communication.getInstance().setSendingMessages(mmOutStream); //Passing the OutStream to the sending class.
    Communication.getInstance().setReceivingMessages(queueReceivingMsg);

    Communication.getInstance().startThreads(); //currently: only start sending thread.

    while (true) {
      try {
        bytes = this.mmInStream.read(buffer, len, buffer.length - len);
        len += bytes;

        if (len >= 3 && buffer[2] != -1) {
          len = 0;
          Log.d(TAG, "run: To Short?");
        } else if (len >= 5) {
          int dataLength = Integer
              .parseInt(String.format("%02X", buffer[3]) + String.format("%02X", buffer[4]), 16);
          if (len == 6 + dataLength) {
            queueReceivingMsg.add(buffer);
            Log.d(TAG, "run: Added to queue");
            len = 0;
          }
          Log.d("BSS", "dataLenght: " + Integer.toString(dataLength) + " len " + len);
        }
      } catch (IOException var5) {
        cancel();
        Communication.getInstance().interruptThreads();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

The important part of sending message Class

```java
public static BlockingQueue<Obj_SendingMessage> sendingMessages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

@Override
  public void run() {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
      if (bGotResponse){
        try{
          sendingMessage = sendingMessages.take();
          send(sendingMessage.getsData());
          bGotResponse = false;
          lTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
          this.interrupt();
        }
      }

      if((System.currentTimeMillis()%500 == 0) && System.currentTimeMillis() <= lTime+1000){
        if(sendingMessage != null){
          send(sendingMessage.getsData());
        }
      } else {
        bGotResponse =true;
      }
    }
  }

//Where the outStream is used
private void write(int[] buffer) {
    try {
      for (int i : buffer) {
        this.mmOutputStream.write(buffer[i]);
      }
    } catch (IOException var3) {

    }
  }
```

To be clear again, the `sendingMessages` is empty all the time, but still the messages get not Received correctly anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by *disturbs* and *not well red anymore*? What happens and did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: BTW: You have some funny code, e.g. `int dataLength = Integer.parseInt(...` can be replaced by `int dataLength = (buffer[3] & 0xff) * 256 + (buffer[4] & 0xff);`. And `catch (IOException var3) { }` is an anti-pattern. Instead use: `catch (IOException var3) { throw new RuntimeException(var3); }`

Comment: @Codo thanks for your comment. This part is not made by me, I have to copy it from an other project. I will tell them that there is a mistake or "better solution".
I deleted the content of the try catch to make the code smaller. I don't think the content is necessary for my problem.

With "disturbed" I mean that the data is not red completely anymore. Like there are some signs missing. To be more clear the original message is 25 long and now I just receive only 10 singes.

Comment: I can't tell you if it's the main cause but the receiving code is flawed. It assumes that `read` will return an entire message and only one messages at a time. That's an incorrect assumption. *BluetoothSocke*'s input stream is a byte stream with no message demarcation. It can return only part of a message or several messages or a message plus part of the next message. The new multi-threaded approach can easily have changed how the input stream buffers and delivers data. As a first step, log all received bytes to check if that's the problem. But it needs to be rewritten anyway.

Comment: @Codo Don't ask me why, but I already made an other application which uses the same receiving code and it works perfectly fine. I know what you are talking about referring to the part wise sending of messages. But I think the way the receiving code is working, it saves ever message part till the message is complete.

Comment: @Codo as you can see the "len" value just gets resetted when it reaches a specific length or is to short. I think this value is used to catch the correct messages.

Comment: It might or might not be the main cause. But it's certainly not correct. Test it for the case of receiving two messages in a single read: the code finds the length to be invalid and discards both messages. Test it for receiving a message plus a partial one: it will find an invalid length and discard the full and the partial message. So the second message is also lost. Test if for the case where only the first two bytes of a message are read: it's discarded. You have probably been lucky so far that the buffering and timing resulting in each read delivering an entire message.

Comment: @Codo I exactly understand what you are talking about, thank you for that background knowledge. 
Is it possible that the other side of the BT, so the client, has a protocol to make sure that there is just a specific length of ever message delivered?
Maybe something like min. 6 signs are delivered? I can't look in the protocol of the client....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposal how robust code for reading messages from the stream could look like. The code can handle partial and multiple messages by:

- Waiting for more data if a message is not complete
- Processing the first message and saving the rest of the data if data for more than one message is available
- Searching for a the marker byte 0xff and retaining the data for the next possibly valid message if invalid data needs to be discard

While writing this code I've noticed another bug in the code. If a message is found, the data is not copied. Instead the buffer is returned. However, the buffer and therefore the returned message might be overwritten by the next message before or while the previous one is processed.

This bug is more severe than the poor decoding of the stream data.

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
private int numUnprocessedBytes = 0;

public void run() {
    ...
    while (true) {
        try {
            int numBytesRead = mmInStream.read(buffer, numUnprocessedBytes, buffer.length - numUnprocessedBytes);
            numUnprocessedBytes += numBytesRead;
            processBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

private void processBytes() {
    boolean tryAgain;
    do {
        tryAgain = processSingleMessage();
    } while (tryAgain);
}

private boolean processSingleMessage() {
    if (numUnprocessedBytes < 5)
        return false; // insufficient data to decode length

    if (buffer[2] != (byte)0xff)
        // marker byte missing; discard some data
        return discardInvalidData();

    int messageLength = (buffer[3] & 0xff) * 256 + (buffer[4] & 0xff);
    if (messageLength > buffer.length)
        // invalid message length; discard some data
        return discardInvalidData();

    if (messageLength > numUnprocessedBytes)
        return false; // incomplete message; wait for more data

    // complete message received; copy it and add it to the queue
    byte[] message = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, messageLength);
    queueReceivingMsg.add(message);

    // move remaining data to the front of buffer
    if (numUnprocessedBytes > messageLength)
        System.arraycopy(buffer, messageLength, buffer, 0, numUnprocessedBytes - messageLength);
    numUnprocessedBytes -= messageLength;

    return numUnprocessedBytes >= 5;
}

private boolean discardInvalidData() {
    // find marker byte after index 2
    int index = indexOfByte(buffer, (byte)0xff, 3, numUnprocessedBytes);
    if (index >= 3) {
        // discard some data and move remaining bytes to the front of buffer
        System.arraycopy(buffer, index - 2, buffer, 0, numUnprocessedBytes - (index - 2));
        numUnprocessedBytes -= index - 2;
    } else {
        // discard all data
        numUnprocessedBytes = 0;
    }
    return numUnprocessedBytes >= 5;
}

static private  int indexOfByte(byte[] array, byte element, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        if (array[i] == element)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```